# Locked Mac find my Mac

Tags: find-my-mac

Find my Mac is locked I wanted to know if there is a way to rebuild a Mac with find my Mac being locked to an Apple ID. I can't remember what I put for my 6 digit pin. Also, is there a way to just get back into it so I can back up my information.

Comment: The first thing to do is unlock it again from iCloud, on any web browser. If you can't remember your iCloud details, start at https://iforgot.apple.com

Answer (score 2):

You need to visit an Apple Store (Genius Bar appointment) to get it unlocked.

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204756

> **How do I unlock my Mac?**
>
> Once you locate your Mac, you can unlock it by
> entering your passcode on the lock screen. If you forget your
> passcode, you'll need to take your Mac to an Apple Authorized Service
> Provider along with your proof of purchase.